# R distance between potential clients accross time

Tags: r

Lately I have posted a similar request but the situation we came to does not work with large data, hence I will try to be more generic so that maybe somebody has a quicker solution.

I have a data table with firms at several points in time and another one with banks. I have managed to produce the longitude and latitude for each city of each bank and each firm. What I would like to do is to find for each firm the average distance between the firm and banks.

For example, let us assume I have the following datasets (I actually have more than 20k banks and several thousand firms) :

```
Data_firm <- data.frame(
  Firm = c("A", "A", "B"),
  time = c("1", "2", "2"),
  Postal_firm = c("20246", "20246", "67720"),
  Longfirm = c("9.2","9.2","7.8"),
  Latfirm = c("42.6", "42.6","48.7")
  )

Data_bank <- data.frame(
  Bank = c("AB", "AC"),
  Postal_bank = c("50670", "88290"),
  Longbank = c("-1.2","6.8"),
  Latbank = c("48.7", "48.0"),
  Assets = c("100", "200"),
  first_entry = c("2","1")
)
```

I would like to add a column to Data_firm with the average distance (I calculate them with distance harvestine) between the firm and all banks in the system at a given time. In the example above, the first row with company should only calculate the distance between A and AC but in the second row and third cow, it should be the average distance between A and AB and AC because bank AB arrives in period 2.

I don't see how to do this given the fact that I have 4000 firms across 300 000 observations and 20874 local banks as potential credit provider. Would anybody have an idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The needed computations are quite well suitable to be parallelized. If your computer has got several cores and a reasonable RAM, that can be done.

Comment: Is the presumption that banks stay open indefinitely following first_entry?

Comment: @JonSpring actually I did not want to bother you with that point and try to adapt the program afterward but I also have a variable bank_exit with the time of exit for each bank...

Comment: @PaulSmith what do you mean by parallelized ?

Comment: @Nicolas See: [Parallel computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) and [Quick Intro to Parallel Computing in R](https://nceas.github.io/oss-lessons/parallel-computing-in-r/parallel-computing-in-r.html)